# In C, almost all indexes from an array have `0x0`, but some try to automatically access memory?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to create an array of strings in C. My plan is for the program to read line from a file and them gradually build this array.

But I noticed that after I allocate memory to this array, some of its indices are `0x0`, and some are trying to access memory in a weird manner. For example:

```c
char** arr_docs = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

In `gdb`, I'll try to see the memory addresses of many of this array's indexes:

```c
arr_docs[0]
> 0x0
arr_docs[1]
> 0x0
arr_docs[2]
> 0x0
arr_docs[3]
> 0x1fae1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1fae1>
arr_docs[4]
> 0x0
```

Wait, what?? Why does `arr_docs[3]` is trying to access that address?

I have also noticed that when I'm building the array of strings, the program correctly puts the intended string in `arr_docs[0]`, but at some point in the loop (In the debugger, it shows that is when i == 4), arr_docs[0] get allocated again! Here's the for-loop code and the behavior `arr_docs[0]` shows in the debugger:

```
void getlinha(char* buf, FILE* arq){
    fgets(buf, 50, arq);
    int size = strlen(buf);
    // final \n replaced by \0
    buf[size-1] = '\0';
}
char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        //char* temp = (char*)malloc(50);
        arr_docs[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        getlinha(temp, input);
        strcpy(arr_docs[i], temp);
    }
```

In the debugger, when i < 4:

```c
> arr_docs[0]: 0x55555555a530 "sigaa 2"
```

When i == 4 (More specifically, when `arr_docs[4] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));`):

```c
> arr_docs[0] : 0x55555555a530 "\260\245UUUU"
```

I'm completely lost.

---

**Update**

Following recommendations, I edited the code. Dumped dynamic memory allocation, since I know how many strings to store. Still, some problems arise. The new code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getlinha(char* buf, FILE* arq){
    fgets(buf, 50, arq);
    int size = strlen(buf);
    // final \n replaced by \0
    buf[size-1] = '\0';
}

int main(void){
    char* arr_docs[6];
    int i;
    FILE* input = fopen("file.input", "r");
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        getlinha(arr_docs[i], input);
    }
}
```

In this program, `fgets` rises Segmentation fault error;
In the debugger, `arr_docs[0]` is correctly assigned. But `arr_docs[1]` throws the error:

```c
arr_docs[1]
> 0x5555555552bd <__libc_csu_init+77> "H\203\303\001H9\335u\352H\203\304\b[]A\\A]A^A_\303ff.\017\037\204"

fgets(arr_docs[1], 50, input)
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:314
```

---

**Update 2**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void getlinha(char* buf, FILE* arq){
    fgets(buf, 50, arq);
    int size = strlen(buf);
    // final \n replaced by \0
    buf[size-1] = '\0';
}

int main(void){
    char* arr_docs[6];
    int i;
    FILE* input = fopen("file.input", "r");
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        // assuming the upper bound size of one doc is 50 chars
        arr_docs[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        getlinha(arr_docs[i], input);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        free(arr_docs[i]);
        arr_docs[i] = NULL;
    }
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc()` doesn't initialize the memory that it returns, so it can contain anything.

Comment: `calloc()` gives you a zero-initialized buffer

Comment: `arr_docs[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` only allocates 1 character. You can't read a 50-character line into that buffer.

Comment: [In C you shouldn't cast the return of `malloc` (or `calloc`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/).

Comment: How many strings do you expect to store, having allocated `sizeof(char*)` bytes?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char*))` only allocates memory for 1 pointer.

Comment: So you're causing lots of buffer overflows in your code, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Hey guys: I'm planning on storing 6 strings in the array. I added a update in the post, where I eliminated the cast and some other recommendations were applied. Still, some errors arise. How should I proceed?

Comment: If you know how many strings you want to store, or even just an upper bound on the number of strings, then why are you messing with dynamic allocation?

Comment: You're still blasting through buffer overflows. Ex: how big a string do you think you can store in the buffer allocated with `char *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));` ? Do yo know how many chars that buffer is (e.g. do you know how many chars `sizeof(*temp)` is) ?  Run your code in a *debugger*. Each time it tries to puke on itself the debugger will *probably* halt and the stack trace can reveal how you got to where you are. Memory watch like valgrind, or `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` can also help immensely.

Comment: `char* arr_docs[6];` is an array of 6 pointers. Those pointers are not initialized, they point to "random" addresses. Passing any of those pointers as the first argument of `fgets` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: I finally got it. I added a final update. It works as expected. It was my fault. I was thinking that allocating a pointer to char wouldn't need to specify the upper bound of chars that string could contain.

Comment: your final update is full of errors

Comment: @0___________ mind explaining them? I corrected some errors I noticed (like forgetting `fclose`), but I can't see the "full of errors" part.

Comment: for example free(input)

Comment: Corrected that already. Any other erros u notice, would be happy to correct them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still some problems in your latest update:

- you do not check for `fopen` failure to open the file
- you do not check for memory allocation failure
- you do not check for `fgets()` failure
- if a line read by `fgets()` is longer than 49 bytes including the newline, it will be spill to the next array.
- you have undefined behavior if `strlen(buf)` returns 0.
- you overwrite the last byte of `buf` without checking that it is a newline.

Here is a modified version without dynamic memory allocation that truncates long lines:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// read a line of input
// return -1 and set buf to the empty string at end of file
// otherwise return the line length
// line read is truncated to fit in buf and null terminated if size>0
// truncation can be detected by testing if the return value >= buffer length.
int getlinha(char *buf, int size, FILE *fp) {
    int c, i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < size)
            buf[j++] = (char)c;
    }
    if (size > 0)
        buf[j] = '\0';
    if (i == 0 && c == EOF)
        return -1;
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    char arr_docs[6][50];
    int i, n;
    FILE *input = fopen("file.input", "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", "file.input", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    for (n = 0; n < 6; n++) {
        // assuming the upper bound size of one doc is 50 chars
        if (getlinha(arr_docs[n], sizeof arr_docs[n], input) < 0)
            break;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i + 1, arr_docs[i]);
    }
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these corrections. I assumed the maximum size of the string is 50 because my teacher is using a file where the longest line has 15 chars. But in a production or serious environment, I should consider the possibility of a 50+ line.

Comment: @PedroVinícius: you should consider using `getline`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that that "0x0" in the first part of your question is not an address (which should be 20 bit) but rather the value stored at that position. With `malloc()` you allocate memory as it is, meaning that it's not freed from the values that were stored before being assigned. If you want it to be initialized to 0 instead, use ```calloc()``.